# Change Value of Nested Array Dynamically

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I am trying to dynamically change my nested state in redux. The "change" or "data.payload.peferenceType" is the value I want to change. Like for example it can give out `hud.vehicle.minimap`. I tried doing the first thing which was `newState[change] = data.payload.value`. But it dosent really work. Ignore the phone and voice. I will add values there later. Any help would be appreaciated, thanks!

```
const initialState = {
  hud: {
    hud_saves: {
      current_hud: 1,
    },
    vehicle: {
      minimap: true,
      speedometer_fps: 15,
    },
    compass: {
      showCompass: true,
      showDirections: true,
      compass_fps: 15,
    },
    status: {
      health: { display: true, hide: 75 },
      armor: { display: true, hide: 75 },
      hunger: { display: true, hide: 75 },
      thirst: { display: true, hide: 75 },
    },
  },
  phone: {},
  voice: {},
};

const PreferencesStore = (state = initialState, data: IShow) => {
  switch (data.type) {
    case "setPreference":
      var newState = { ...state };
      var change = data.payload.peferenceType;

      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: check my answer. is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to split the key based on `.` character and then loop inside the initial state object in order to find the path.

Key part is to loop and leave the last element in order to update its value outside the loop.

`i < split.length - 1;` and not `i <= split.length - 1;`

```js
const initialState = {
  hud: {
    hud_saves: {
      current_hud: 1
    },
    vehicle: {
      minimap: true,
      speedometer_fps: 15
    },
    compass: {
      showCompass: true,
      showDirections: true,
      compass_fps: 15
    },
    status: {
      health: { display: true, hide: 75 },
      armor: { display: true, hide: 75 },
      hunger: { display: true, hide: 75 },
      thirst: { display: true, hide: 75 }
    }
  },
  phone: {},
  voice: {}
};

function alterValue(obj, str) {
  let split = str.split(".");
  let obj2 = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
    if (obj2 == null) {
      obj2 = obj[split[i]];
    } else {
      obj2 = obj2[split[i]];
    }
  }

  obj2[split[split.length - 1]] = "11111111111";

  console.log("INITIAL STATE VS FINAL STATE", initialState, newState);
}
let newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState));
alterValue(newState, "hud.vehicle.minimap");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use spread operator over here if it nested for example you want to update `minimap` from `vehicle`

```
return {
    ...state,
    hud: {
        ...state.hud,
        vehicle : {
            ...state.hud.vehicle
            minimap : data.payload.peferenceType
        }
    },
};
```